# What is the categorical operad whose algebras are the (based) symmetric monoidal categories?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

What is the  categorical operad whose algebras are the (based) symmetric monoidal categories?

Note that the definition of symmetric monoidal category can be found here.
[https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+monoidal+category#:~:text=A%20symmetric%20monoidal%20category%20is,categorical%20products%20may%20be%20commutative](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+monoidal+category#:%7E:text=A%20symmetric%20monoidal%20category%20is,categorical%20products%20may%20be%20commutative).

A symmetric monoidal category is based if the unit is strict.

I tried defining it myself but have had no luck. Can someone please tell me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by based symmetric monoidal categories?

Comment: See this, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+monoidal+category#:~:text=A%20symmetric%20monoidal%20category%20is,categorical%20products%20may%20be%20commutative.

Comment: Also, based means the unit is strict.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by the unit being strict (i.e. perhaps $I \otimes A = A$) but one reference you might consult is *Infinity Operads and Monoidal Categories with Group Equivariance*. In that text Donald Yau outlines a general procedure for constructing all kinds of categorical operads that are in a coherent sense acted upon by a "group $G$ action operad". Then the algebras over those categorical operads "acted on" by a $G$-action operad give you braided, symmetric, ribbon monoidal categories by varying $G = B_n$ (braids), $G = S_n$, etc (I'm paraphrasing a lot here)

Comment: That is exactly what I mean by strict.

Comment: Also, thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking and found the answer. The answer I found comes from the link
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+monoidal+category#:%7E:text=A%20symmetric%20monoidal%20category%20is,categorical%20products%20may%20be%20commutative . Apparently, a symmetric monoidal category is equivalently a a category that is equipped with the structure of an algebra over the little k-cubes operad for k≥3.

Comment: The algebras are actually symmetric  monoidal $\infty$-categories.